# React cloned elements do not update with state

Tags: reactjs

I'm cloning a div:

```
const scroll_div = document.querySelector('.cryptobar_wrapper');
const items_wrapper = scroll_div.querySelector('.items_wrapper');
const items_wrapper_2 = items_wrapper.cloneNode(true)
scroll_div.appendChild(items_wrapper_2);
```

Here is the html:

```
        <div className={'items_wrapper'}>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={btc_icon} alt={'btc_icon'}/>
                <p>{btc_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={cardano_icon} alt={'cardano_icon'}/>
                <p>{cardan_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={dogecoin_Logo} alt={'dogecoin_icon'}/>
                <p>{dogecoin_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={eth_icon} alt={'eth_icon'}/>
                <p>{eth_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={bnb_icon} alt={'bnb_icon'}/>
                <p>{bnb_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={bnb_icon} alt={'bnb_icon'}/>
                <p>{bnb_price} $</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

the price of each is set using `useState`:

```
const [btc_price, set_btc_price] = useState(0)
const [cardan_price, set_cardan_price] = useState(0)
const [dogecoin_price, set_dogecoin_price] = useState(0)
const [eth_price, set_eth_price] = useState(0)
const [bnb_price, set_bnb_price] = useState(0)
```

In the chrome dev tools, it is showing that I have two `items_wrapper` divs but only the elements of the first `items_wrapper` div are updating with the state, the second elements do not update and stay at 0

[image]

Comment: You should (almost) never manipulate the DOM manually while using React. It completely defeats the purpose, and there's no way to guarantee correct behavior.

Comment: @BrianThompson I'm trying to create an infinite horizontal scroll how can I do this without manipulating DOM?